# neo4j cypher : unable to create and use an index

Tags: indexing, neo4j, cypher

I'd like to create a few indexes on neo4j 2.0 but I can't understand what's wrong here. Starting with a fresh database, my input command looks like

```
CREATE INDEX ON :user(name);
CREATE INDEX ON :root(root);
CREATE INDEX ON :origin(origin);
CREATE INDEX ON :gender(gender);
create (n1:root {root : 'root'}),(n2:gender {gender : 'female'}),(n3:gender {gender : 'male'}),(n4:origin {origin : 'english (modern)' }),(n5:origin {origin : 'finnish' }),(n6:user {name : 'aaliyah'}),(n7:user {name : 'aapeli'}),(n8:user {name : 'aapo'});
```

Everything looks fine at this point ( see the output below) but when I try to use the index I get an error:

```
neo4j-sh (0)$ start n=node:user(name="aapo") return n;
MissingIndexException: Index `user` does not exist
```

Any idea why this is happening ? Note that creating the nodes before the index doesn't change anything.

Thanks in advance

Output of my first command :

```
neo4j-sh (0)$ CREATE INDEX ON :user(name);
+-------------------+
| No data returned. |
+-------------------+
Indexes added: 1
235 ms
neo4j-sh (0)$ CREATE INDEX ON :root(root);
+-------------------+
| No data returned. |
+-------------------+
Indexes added: 1
246 ms
neo4j-sh (0)$ CREATE INDEX ON :origin(origin);
+-------------------+
| No data returned. |
+-------------------+
Indexes added: 1
173 ms
neo4j-sh (0)$ CREATE INDEX ON :gender(gender);
+-------------------+
| No data returned. |
+-------------------+
Indexes added: 1
160 ms
neo4j-sh (0)$ create (n1:root {root : 'root'}),(n2:gender {gender : 'female'}),(n3:gender {gender : 'male'}),(n4:origin {origin : 'english (modern)' }),(n5:origin {origin : 'finnish' }),(n6:user {name : 'aaliyah'}),(n7:user {name : 'aapeli'}),(n8:user {name : 'aapo'});
+-------------------+
| No data returned. |
+-------------------+
Nodes created: 8
Properties set: 8
Labels added: 8
1027 ms
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The indexes created via Cypher are called Schema indexes, and are not to be used in the `START` clause. The `START` clause index lookups are reserved for the legacy indexes that you create via autoindexing or through the non-Cypher APIs.

In order to use the :user index you've created, you can do this:

```
match n:user
where n.name="aapo"
return n;
```

Try it out with `profile`.

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer ( I replaced `where name=` by `where n.name=` to make it work though ).
Is there a difference of performances between the two approaches ?

Comment: That's what I meant to put. Sorry about that.