# Neo4j Index not available

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I try to create an index in Neo4j, but it seems like it is not working. I insert data with the following codes snippet.

```
 create index on :`Person`(`name`)
 create (_0:`Person` {`name`:"Andres"})
 create (_1:`Person` {`name`:"Mark"})
 create _0-[:`KNOWS`]->_1
```

The code here works fine. But when I try to fetch data with cypher command

```
START n=node:name(name= 'Bob')
RETURN n
```

I've got an error

```
Index `name` does not exist
Neo.ClientError.Schema.NoSuchIndex
```

But as you can see above, I declare an index name. What do I query wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

either you must use automatic index - http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/auto-indexing.html - where you first specify in the neo4j config file which parameters would be indexed (than start/restart the server)

or when using manual indexing - http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/indexing-add.html - you must include each new node into the index manualy like this:

```
MATCH (n:Person)
USING INDEX n:Person(name)
WHERE n.name = 'Bob'
RETURN n
```

view also [neo4j cypher : unable to create and use an index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16809862/neo4j-cypher-unable-to-create-and-use-an-index)

Comment: Your first URL is no longer working. Some additional info can be provided bu this http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/indexing-create-advanced.html and this http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/configuration-settings.html